# Is there an elegant NestJS-style way to check entity owner in TypeORM

Tags: orm, nestjs, crud, typeorm

I have an application built with NestJS and TypeORM.

There's an entity with an owner (user_id for example), and there are user roles.

So I wanted to find out if there is an elegant way to allow an “Admin” for example to list and edit all entities and all other roles to list and edit only entities that they own, with their `user_id`.

Of course, I could do this by writing some code, but I wonder if there's a nice unified approach so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.